# What does the image on the back of the LotR discs represent?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, cover-art

Been watching the extended blu-ray version of LotR and I noticed this symbol on the back cover. Don't think I've seen this whilst watching the films, anyone know what it represents?

[image]

Comment: It's the Irish Film Classification Office logo, indicating that the film isn't suitable for those under 12.

Comment: @Valorum, huh, I thought that was the running time in hours...

Comment: Pfft. You casual. I expect you only watched the theatrical versions, not the Directors cuts.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's a depiction of the badge of the House of Elrond from the LotR films.

This art piece depicting the badge comes from Weta Workshop designer [Daniel Falconer](http://www.polyvore.com/lotr_elven_house_badges_daniel/thing?id=49079158).

[image]
<sub><sup>Image courtesy of [The Lord of the Rings: The Art of The Fellowship of the Ring](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119.The_Lord_of_the_Rings)</sup></sub>

---

> ELVEN INSIGNIA - Daniel Falconer
>
> These badges were used to represent the various Elven armies that
> might appear in the Second Age sequences. Gil-galad's was a slight
> reworking of the one Tolkien himself created, and similarly **the Houses
> of both Elrond and Galadriel borrowed elements from his concepts for
> their respective fathers, Eärendil and Finarfin.**
>
> The other designs
> were entirely Dan's inventions, although clearly in keeping with the
> others. The designs were intended to appear on the breasts of the
> Elres' armor and were also incorporated by the art  department for use
> in their Elven banners.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the actual panel that your image comes from (complete with the signature that was cropped out), along with a quote from the LOTR artbook.

Comment: Brilliant stuff, many thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

They're designed after the fashion of Tolkien's Elven insignia, but the overall shapes are wrong- The badge for an Elvish house is supposed to be in the shape of a square. Personal badges are a bit different. A man's badge is in the shape of a lozenge (a square tipped 45 degrees on its side), and a woman's badge is circular. The badge they made for Galadriel is almost accurate, but as they intended for it to represent her army rather than Galadriel herself, it should be in the shape of a square.

Comment: Interesting, but not an answer to the question asked

Comment: Do you have a canon source for those rules?

Comment: Are you basing this on something that Tolkien wrote, or that one of his approved illustrators presented?